# CSS transition does not animate on toggle

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I made a little accordion that I would like to animate.
I have the following code but the animation as written is not working and I don't know why.

I know it's somehow complicated to make the height to work, but I managed to find a work around using `max-height`.

I would like my `div` to have an animated width and height to make it feel like you unfold it.

The weird behaviour is that if you resize the window, everything seems animated...

```js
document.getElementById("ping").onclick = function () {
  console.log(this);
  this.children[1].classList.toggle("active");
};
```

```css
.content.active {
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px;
  transition-property: width, max-height;
  transition-duration: 400ms, 100ms;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.305, 0, 0, 1.015);
  transition-delay: 400ms, 100ms;
  width: 40vw;
  background: orange;
}

.content {
  width: 0px;
  max-height: 0px;
  transition-property: width, max-height;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.305, 0.000, 0.000, 1.015);
  transition-duration: 400ms, 100ms;
  transition-delay: 100ms, 100ms;
  background: orange;
  display: none;
}

.cat.active {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<section id="item0">

  <div id="ping" class="cat">
    <div class="title active" style="">
      <a>Open</a>

    </div>
    <div class="content" style="">
      <div>
        <div class="images">
          first test <br>
          another
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: does it have to be a `max-height`-animation or is animating the `height` fine?

Comment: the height is fine, but I've read you can't animated height...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Only apply the `transition` parameters to the initial state, not to the `.active` state/class.

2.) Don't use `display:none` and `block`, but instead transition between `max-height: 0` and `width: 0` and their ".active" values.

3.) To hide the overflowing contents (which would still be visible), apply `overflow: hidden` to the initial state

```js
document.getElementById("ping").onclick = function () {
  console.log(this);
  this.children[1].classList.toggle("active");
};
```

```css
.content.active {
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 40vw;
}

.content {
  max-height: 0;
  width: 0px;
  transition-property: width, max-height;
  transition-duration: 400ms, 100ms;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.305, 0, 0, 1.015);
  transition-delay: 400ms, 100ms;
  background: orange;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cat.active {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<section id="item0">

  <div id="ping" class="cat">
    <div class="title active" style="">
      <a>Open</a>

    </div>
    <div class="content" style="">
      <div>
        <div class="images">
          first test <br>
          another
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```